# Can I deploy web service api from WPF App which is in Visual C# project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, rest, asp.net-web-api

I am very new to ASP.NET and stuck in this problem for a very long time.
I have a WPF App (.NET Framework) that currently works. It's a program being used for controlling some external device (a Robot). I have the C# project of that WPF App as an editable project in my Visual studio 2017.

What I want to do is use that program (WPF App) to deploy web API service and use fuction in WPF App from the web API, for example I have command `A.FORWARD` to move the robot forward in the button in the WPF App, I want to make an web API service calling `localhost:XXXX/api/moveforward` to call that command (`A.FORWARD`).

First,I tried creating web API service with .NET Framework 4.6.1 and copying code and dependencies for controlling robot from WPF App to it. But after deploying web API, I found out that the external device (robot) is not reachable from web API.

Then secondly I tried copying all code for deploying API service to the WPF App. But I found out the API service won't run (`Application_Start()` in `Global.asax.cs`) and I cant force it to run.

To forced the WPF App to run API, I copied all needed file especially `Global.asax.cs` to run API which contain this

```
public void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

...and I add it to call by clicking some button from `MainWindow.xaml.cs`.

```
public void ButtonEmotion_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    new Global().Application_Start();
}
```

those effort says:

> Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in
>   System.Web.dll An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.dll
>  This
>   method cannot be called during the application's pre-start
>   initialization phase.

Comment: did you tried self hosted web API, have a look at this link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/older-versions/self-host-a-web-api

Comment: diging what you suggested for many hours, I finally figured it out thanks a lot. youre a god for me

Comment: please mark the comment as useful ;